# Best way to read Spring Multipartfile line by line in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, java-8

What is the best handle a csv Spring Multipartfile?
I have used something like this before:

```
public void handleFile(MultipartFile multipartFile){
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
        IOUtils.readLines(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .stream()
                .forEach(this::handleLine);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}

private void handleLine(String s) {
    // do stuff per line
}
```

As far as I know, this first loads the whole file into a list in memory before processing it, which will probably take quite some time for files with tens of thousends of lines.

Is there a way to handle it line by line without the overhead of implementing the iteration by hand (i.e. using stuff like `read()`, `hasNext(`), ...)?
I am looking for something concise similar to this example for files from the file system:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.csv"))) {
        stream.forEach(this::handleLine);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to handle each line yourself, instead of letting a CSV parsing library handle the InputStream?

Comment: Will it fit your needs ? https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: @VGR can you recommend a library that I can look into?

Comment: @RUAROThibault I also stumbeld accros this article, but was wondering if there was a more modern way to do it. This article is 6 years old after all.

Comment: Do you know how old is Java 8 ? 6 years old ;)

Comment: Yeah but maybe Spring or Apache or someone als has found a fancy way since then.

Comment: The bufferedReader solution seems appropriate anyway. I didn't hear any news for reading files (but I don't know everything). If you find something, don't hesitate to add it as an answer of your own question

Comment: I have found [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to be fairly reliable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In cases when you have InputStream you can use this one:

```
InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .lines()
                    .forEach(this::handleLine);
```

In other cases:

No matter whether it is multipart file or you have multiple independent files, there are many approaches to do it in Java 8 using `Stream` API:

**Solution 1:**

If your files are in  different directories you can do it this way:

Imagine you have a `List` of `String` which contains paths of your files like below:

```
List<String> files = Arrays.asList(
                "/test/test.txt",
                "/test2/test2.txt");
```

Then you can read all lines of above files as below:

```
files.stream().map(Paths::get)
        .flatMap(path -> {
            try {
                return Files.lines(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Stream.empty();
        }).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Solution 2:**

You can also read all lines of files that exist in `/test/ehsan` directory using `Files.walk` in the following way:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get("/test/ehsan"), 1)) {
    stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .flatMap(path -> {
                try {
                    return Files.lines(path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return Stream.empty();
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And if you want to read all lines of files in `/test/ehsan` directory **recursively** you can do it this way:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get("/test/ehsan"))) {
    stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .flatMap(path -> {
                try {
                    return Files.lines(path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return Stream.empty();
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you can see the second parameter to `Files.walk` specifies the maximum number of directory levels to visit and if you don't pass it the default will be used which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

**Solution 3:**

Lets not stop here, we can go further. what if we wanted to read all lines of files exist in two completely different directories for example `/test/ehsan` and `/test2/ehsan1`?

We can do it but we should be cautious, `Stream` should not be so long( because it reduces readability of our program) it will be better to break them in separate methods, However because it is not possible to write multiple methods here I will write in one place how to do that:

Imagine you have a `List` of `String` which contains paths of your directories like below

```
list<String> dirs = Arrays.asList(
                "/test/ehsan",
                "/test2/ehsan1");
```

Then we can do that this way:

```
dirs.stream()
        .map(Paths::get)
        .flatMap(path -> {
            try {
                return Files.walk(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Stream.empty();
        })
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .flatMap(path -> { 
            try {
                return Files.lines(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Stream.empty();
        })
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Your solutions all consider files on the file system. I was talking about Spring Multipartfile (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html), which usually isn't. I edited my Question to clarify that.

Comment: @Schlaagi I've just added update that you can use in your special case

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> readCSV(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                records.add(line);
            }
        }
        return records;
}
```

Comment: This is basically the implementation of IOUtils.readLines. Not what I was looking for.